# Dynamic time warping data visualization

Tags: classification, data-visualization, dynamic-time-warping

I am using dynamic time warping to extract similarity between sequences. Basically, my sequences are consist of simple number (chain codes) not a signal or any time series.

I did the backtracking and finding the optimal warp path of my sequences, and also plot the optimal path of the two sequences (one of it is the sequence template).

My question is, besides looking at the distance between sequences (lowest distance means it's a perfect match with the template), what can i discuss or extract from plotting the optimal path as shown in the figure below?

[image: optimum warping path]

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the optimal warping path (which in case of a=b, is the diagonal of the DTW distance matrix) with the actual warping path of two sequences, you can understand which part of the sequence is "off".

A great example can be found in this [presentation](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-M/slides/04.5.TimeSeries2.pdf) on side 4 / slide 8.